# Keep a coordinates system from OpenGl to OpenXR

Tags: c++, opengl, openxr

I’m programming in C++ with OpenXR SDK.

I have to “translate” an OpenGL Sample in VR with OpenXR.

It’s already done!

However, the coordinate system is not the same and I don’t know how to fix that...

Can u help me?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Hard to tell anything without code, screenshots, etc

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov I don't know what to do with the code. That's the problem...
With my sample, I have 2 windows when I build : a OpenGL Windows and a VR WIndow (available in the headset).

I drew a cube at the origin of the coordinate system but it is in front of me in the OpenGL Window and on my right in the VR Window (I have to look at my right with the headset).

That's why it seems that the the systems positions are not the same.
I think I have to log the differents coordinate to imagine a translation matrix and use it. But I don't know how to dot that.

Do u have an idea ?

Comment: Depends on where your camera is placed and where it looks. If you put it at point e.g. (0, 0, 1), in OpenGL I think it should appear in front of you (because camera by default looks at negative Z direction). If it appears at the right in VR, it might mean here camera by default looks at negative X direction. You can try making a transformation matrix to flip axes. E.g. taking an identity 4x4 matrix, and flipping 1st and 3rd columns (corresponding to X and Z). It might not work immediately, you can try different combinations, with -1 also